# Sort variables by letter in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, sorting, dart

I have a class where I declare many variables concurrently.

Is there any combination of keys or extension to sort them by letters?

I use the IDE AndroidStudio 2022 and the code is in Dart.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can sort the members automatically, but the actions aren't assigned to a shortcut by default.

### IntelliJ

Windows: <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

MacOs: <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Type `Sort Members in Dart File`

[image: Sort members in IntelliJ]

### VScode

Windows: <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

MacOs: <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

Type `> Dart: Sort Members`

[image: Sort members in VScode]

Comment: the option sort lines , OK, thanks

Comment: this arrow sign makes it completely unclear that it is ```Shift``` key